# Why are my DataGridView columns not colorizing as they should?

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-core, datagridview

Based on [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.backgroundcolor?view=netcore-3.1), I added the following code, in an attempt to make the base background color of my cells/rows yellow and the alternating ones lightblue:

```
dataGridView1.BackgroundColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;
dataGridView1.AlternatingRowsDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightBlue;
```

What happens in reality is that only the alternating/every other columns are affected, and I'm not so sure that the color is really light blue:

[image]

Why is the background color remaining the default white for half of the rows?

### UPDATE

I revisited that microsoft page, and tried the following code:

```
dataGridView1.DefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor = 
    System.Drawing.Color.LightYellow;
dataGridView1.DefaultCellStyle.SelectionForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
dataGridView1.RowHeadersDefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor = 
    System.Drawing.Color.Empty;
```

...but it only colorizes one cell, not all, as its comment ("// Set the selection background color for all the cells.") claims it will do.

Here is how it looks now, with the above code:

[image]

Adding the third/final line made no difference either way, although it has the comment "// Set RowHeadersDefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor so that its default
// value won't override DataGridView.DefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is the background color remaining the default white for half of
> the rows?

→ Settings these properties:

```
dataGridView1.BackgroundColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;
dataGridView1.AlternatingRowsDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightBlue;
```

you're defining the background Color of the DataGridView, which is the background Color of the Control itself, not the background Color of its Cells (and the background Color of alternate Rows).

→ With these other properties:

```
dataGridView1.DefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor = Color.LightYellow;
dataGridView1.DefaultCellStyle.SelectionForeColor = Color.Black;
dataGridView1.RowHeadersDefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor = Color.Empty;
```

[SelectionBackColor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcellstyle.selectionbackcolor) and [SelectionForeColor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcellstyle.selectionforecolor), set the [DataGridViewCellStyle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcellstyle) Color of a Cells when selected, not in their normal state, which is determined by the general property, [DefaultCellStyle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.defaultcellstyle), of the DataGridView. All other styles inherit from this (see the ***Important Note***).

**Designer Note**: Setting the `DefaultCellStyle` - in the PropertyGrid - to non default values, because of inheritance and a glitch in the Designer of the `DataGridViewCellStyle` class, may not generate the expected result, both at design-time and run-time: the ForeColor and/or BackColor values are ignored and possibly reset to default. WrapMode and Alignment are reset to default values. If that's the case, set the [RowTemplate.DefaultCellStyle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.rowtemplate) instead.

The `DefaultCellStyle` can be overridden using other properties that can redefine some or all the general properties:

- [RowsDefaultCellStyle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.rowsdefaultcellstyle)
  Redefines some of the styles of all Cells in a Row. Other styles and more general-use properties can be applied to all Rows using the [RowTemplate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.rowtemplate) property.
- [AlternatingRowsDefaultCellStyle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.alternatingrowsdefaultcellstyle)
  Overrides `DefaultCellStyle` and `RowsDefaultCellStyle` to set the backcolor of alternating rows.  It can be overridden by:
- [DataGridViewRow.DefaultCellStyle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewrow.defaultcellstyle)
  Overrides the style of a Row.  Can be overridden by:
- [DataGridViewCell.Style](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcell.style)
  Set the style specific for a Cell.

See also: [Cell Styles in the Windows Forms DataGridView Control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/cell-styles-in-the-windows-forms-datagridview-control)

▶ **IMPORTANT NOTE**:
The more specific a style is, the more it can compromise the DataGridView performance when presenting a large number of Row (*large* is undefined, it means that when the grid is scrolled, you notice some form of *glitches* in the graphics and some delay). Since the general `DefaultCellStyle` is used to determine the presentation of a Cell, setting Styles for each Row or Cell causes the Control to read and set the Style for each Row or Cell that redefines the default style.
This *activity* can of course complicate the presentation. When coupled with the automatic Column sizing that measures all Cells, the performance takes a bad hit.

To set the default BackColor of Rows when **`AlternatingRowsDefaultCellStyle`** is used, you can either set the `DataGridView.DefaultCellStyle` or the `DataGridView.RowsDefaultCellStyle`.
Which one to choose depends on the design of the DataGridView.

You can use `DefaultCellStyle` if you need to specify this property to define the general aspect of the grid:

```
[DataGridView].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
```

or `RowsDefaultCellStyle`, if the `DefaultCellStyle` basic properties (ForeColor, BackColor, Font etc.) are inherited from the DataGridView's Parent and you need to override this behavior per-Row, since the `AlternatingRowsDefaultCellStyle` override has already been specified.

```
[DataGridView].RowsDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
```

Thus, if setting the `DefaultCellStyle` can work in your case, use this instead of `RowsDefaultCellStyle` (which is more specific).

**Some more information here**:

- [Best Practices for Scaling the Windows Forms DataGridView Control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/best-practices-for-scaling-the-windows-forms-datagridview-control)
- [How to: Set Default Cell Styles for the Windows Forms DataGridView Control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/how-to-set-default-cell-styles-for-the-windows-forms-datagridview-control)
- [How to: Use the Row Template to Customize Rows in the DataGridView Control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/use-the-row-template-to-customize-rows-in-the-datagrid)

Answer (score 1):

Use the [DataGridViewRow.RowDefaultStyle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewrow.defaultcellstyle?view=netcore-3.1) to set the default row color. The example in that link shows in detail how to do this.

The DataGridViewRow.BackColor applies to the area not filled with rows.