# Can't change color of specific rows in a DataGridView. DefaultCellStyle.BackColor not working

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to change the color of some specific rows in a DataGridView, but for some reason DefaultCellStyle.BackColor is not working. If I change the color of the whole table, it works. But if I try to do it to a single row, it just doesn't work. This is the code I wrote:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView2.Rows)
        {
            if (Convert.ToString(row.Cells[20].Value) != "")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Inside if"); //With this messagebox I make sure I get inside the if.
                row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;//This just doesn't work.
                
            }
        }
```

I also tried to change the color of just one row, but had no luck.

```
dataGridView2.Rows[1].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
```

I don't know what am I missing or if I'm just too dumb to see the problem. I've already searched in different forums for an answer but I couldn't find any.

Comment: Are you setting the backcolors in some other code as well? e.g. setting a spcefic cell's colors will override the defaultcellstyle..

Comment: @TaW Nope. I think in the designer I just changed the color of the selected row? (I did this programmatically, but for some reason it also shows on the designer) and some other things, but nothing to do with cell's backcolor.

Comment: *I also tried to change the color of just one row, but had no luck.* - ok. what is the value of the cell's backcolor? `dataGridView2.Rows[1].Cells[0].Style.BackColor` - most specifically, what is the value of IsEmpty (if it's false it's set at the cell level and overrides the default) but also interested to know the other values

Comment: Read the notes here: [Why are my DataGridView columns not colorizing as they should?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64721869/7444103), it may be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `datagridview` control cannot change colors until the form has been shown. If you have this in the `Load` event, move it to the `Shown` event.

OR

You can try putting it in the `DataGridView_CellFormatting` event like this:

```
private void dataGridView2_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    // Assuming 20 is the column index you're looking for
    if (this.dataGridView2.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Index == 20)
    {
        if (e.Value != null)
        {
            string strVal = (string)e.Value;
            if (strVal != "")
            {
                e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
            }
        }
    }
}
```