# How to change current DataGridView Cell Background color?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have seen very topic with that subject, but my question is different.

I have a win form with a DataGrid view on it.I've put DataGrid view Selection Mode in FullRowSelection bcoz I need to know where am I in that gridview.I move in that gridview with keyboard arrow keys Now I want to change current cell back color when I move on grid view with arrow keys.

In this image you can understand my mean.

[image: DatagRidview]

I have checked GridView CurrentCellChanged event but do not understand it.

Comment: Tnx.I do that but it colorize full row. I want to change back color of just cell that my cursur is on it –

Answer (score 1):

Since it appears you want to colorize the DataGridView's `CurrentCell` when the `SelectionMode` is set to `FullRowSelect`, then you can handle the `CellPainting` event and, when the Cell is the `CurrentCell`, set the `e.CellStyle` member to any combination of colors that makes sense in your context.

The `e.CellStyle` value is transient, it's reset when the Cell is painted again using the default values, unless otherwise specified.

```
private void someDataGridView_CellPainting(object sender, DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex < 0 || e.RowIndex < 0) return;
    var dgv = (sender as DataGridView);
    var cell = dgv[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex];
    if (dgv.SelectionMode != DataGridViewSelectionMode.CellSelect && cell == dgv.CurrentCell) {
        // Set any color combination you prefer
        e.CellStyle.SelectionForeColor = Color.White;
        e.CellStyle.SelectionBackColor = Color.Red;
    }
}
```

You may want to read the notes here:
[Why are my DataGridView columns not colorizing as they should?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64721869/7444103)
about different ways of setting the DataGridView styles and their hierarchical relations

Answer (score 0):

to change the row selection color you can add on you Form_Load:

```
dataGridView1.DefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor = Color.Red;
```

feel free to ask any question.