# Why can't I read a DataGridViewCell color set by DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs.CellStyle.Color?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, .net-4.8

I use the CellFormatting event of a `System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView` to set the background color of cells.

Let simply says that the event code is:

```cs
private void someDgv_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e) {
    e.CellStyle.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
}
```

Where someDgv is a `System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView`.

In the grid the cells are green.

Then I iterate on `dgv.Rows` and iterate on each cell to find the background color.
For this I use the following code (from a more complex exporter):

```cs
if (o is System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCell dgvc) {
    Console.WriteLine("here");
    val = (x) => dgvc.Value;
    bkColor = (x) => {
        System.Drawing.Color c = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;                    
        Console.WriteLine(dgvc.HasStyle);
        if (dgvc.HasStyle) {
            c = dgvc.Style.BackColor;
        } else {
            c = dgvc.InheritedStyle.BackColor;
        }
        if (c.IsEmpty || c.Name == "Window") {
            return System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
        }
        return c;
    };
} else {
    val = (x) => x;
    bkColor = (x) => System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
}
```

In my case this code always prints "here", "False" and returns `System.Drawing.Color.Transparent`. That is the value is always read from `InheritedStyle` and is never Green.

The only way I found to overcome this is to rewrite the code of the event as follows:

```cs
private void someDgv_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e) {
    someDgv.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Style.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
}
```

I'm looking for an explanation. I can't found it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/cell-styles-in-the-windows-forms-datagridview-control?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8#setting-styles-dynamically).

Comment: Notes [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76440584/7444103) -- The DataGridViewCellStyle you get there is used for the Cell's presentation, generated by the `GetInheritedStyle()` method, then used by the `GetFormattedValue()` method, then rendered when the Cell is painted in the UI. The Cell's DefaultCellStyle is not affected, otherwise the change would be permanent