# Combobox index change stops cells formatting

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, combobox

I am facing a problem in my WinForms app, where :

Whenever I select an item on my combobox for the first time, the formatting which ensues it is applied. However, after that, the formatting no longer applies and I just have blank cells like in the picture below:

[image: first time]

[image: second time]

Here's my code :

```
int t = 0;
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView2.Rows)
            {
                row.Cells["toleranceMinDataGridViewTextBoxColumn"].Value = "";
                row.Cells["toleranceNomDataGridViewTextBoxColumn"].Value = "";
                row.Cells["toleranceMaxDataGridViewTextBoxColumn"].Value = "";

                row.Cells["toleranceMinDataGridViewTextBoxColumn"].ReadOnly = false;
                row.Cells["toleranceNomDataGridViewTextBoxColumn"].ReadOnly = false;
                row.Cells["toleranceMaxDataGridViewTextBoxColumn"].ReadOnly = false;

            }

            void creation()
            {
                dataGridView2.Columns.OfType<DataGridViewColumn>().ToList().ForEach(col => col.Visible = false);
                dataGridView2.Columns["lotDataGridViewTextBoxColumn"].Visible = true;
                dataGridView2.Columns["ItemDataGridViewTextBoxColumn"].Visible = true;
                dataGridView2.Columns["lotDataGridViewTextBoxColumn"].Visible = true;
                dataGridView2.Columns["ItemDataGridViewTextBoxColumn"].Visible = true;
                dataGridView2.Columns["toleranceMinDataGridViewTextBoxColumn"].Visible = true;
                dataGridView2.Columns["toleranceNomDataGridViewTextBoxColumn"].Visible = true;
                dataGridView2.Columns["toleranceMaxDataGridViewTextBoxColumn"].Visible = true;


                dataGridView2.Columns[$"toleranceMinDataGridViewTextBoxColumn"].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Wheat;
                dataGridView2.Columns[$"toleranceNomDataGridViewTextBoxColumn"].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Wheat;
                dataGridView2.Columns[$"toleranceMaxDataGridViewTextBoxColumn"].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Wheat;
            }

            creation();


            void creationitemsettolerances()
            {
                foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView2.Rows)
                {
                    row.Visible = false;
                }

                foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView2.Rows)
                {
                    if (!(row.Cells[$"{comboBox1.Text + comboBox2.Text}DataGridViewTextBoxColumn"].Value?.ToString() is ""))
                    {
                        row.Visible = true; ;
                    }

                }

                var result = from DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView2.Rows where row.Visible select row;


                foreach (DataGridViewRow row in result)
                {
                    string[] splitter = new string[3];
                    t++;
                    string a = row.Cells[$"{comboBox1.Text + comboBox2.Text}DataGridViewTextBoxColumn"].Value?.ToString();
                    if (a.Contains('-'))
                    {
                        splitter = a.Split('-');
                        row.Cells["toleranceMinDataGridViewTextBoxColumn"].Value = splitter[0];
                        row.Cells["toleranceNomDataGridViewTextBoxColumn"].Value = splitter[1];
                        try { 
                            row.Cells["toleranceMaxDataGridViewTextBoxColumn"].Value = splitter[2];
                        }catch(Exception ex) { Debug.WriteLine(ex); }


                    }
                    else
                    {
                        row.Cells["toleranceNomDataGridViewTextBoxColumn"].Value = a;

                    }
                }
            }

            creationitemsettolerances();


            void formattagedestolerances()
            {
                var result = from DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView2.Rows where row.Visible select row;
                foreach (var row in result)
                {
                    if ((row.Cells["toleranceMinDataGridViewTextBoxColumn"].Value?.ToString() is "") && (row.Cells["toleranceMaxDataGridViewTextBoxColumn"].Value?.ToString() is ""))
                    {
                        string a = row.Cells["toleranceNomDataGridViewTextBoxColumn"].Value?.ToString();
                        var cell = (DataGridViewTextBoxCellEx)row.Cells["toleranceMinDataGridViewTextBoxColumn"];
                        cell.Value = a;
                        cell.ColumnSpan = 3;
                        cell.Style.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
                    }


                }
            }
            formattagedestolerances();



            void definitiondeslots()
            {
                int deb1 = 0;
                int deb2 = 0;
                int fin1 = 0;
                int fin2 = 0;
                int deb3 = 0;
                int fin3 = 0;



                var result = from DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView2.Rows where row.Visible select row;

                fin3 = result.Count() ;


                foreach (var row in result)
                {
                    if (row.Cells["TolerancesDataGridViewTextBoxColumn"].Value?.ToString() is "1")
                    {
                        
                         if ((row.Cells["lotDataGridViewTextBoxColumn"].Value?.ToString() is "2") && (deb2 == 0))
                        {
                            deb2 = row.Index;
                            fin1 = row.Index - 1;
                        }
                        else if ((row.Cells["lotDataGridViewTextBoxColumn"].Value?.ToString() is "3") && (deb3 == 0))
                        {
                            fin2 = row.Index - 1;
                            deb3 = row.Index;
                        }

                    }
                    else if(row.Cells["TolerancesDataGridViewTextBoxColumn"].Value?.ToString() is "2")
                    {
                        if ((row.Cells["lotDataGridViewTextBoxColumn"].Value?.ToString() is "1") && (deb1 == 0))
                        {
                            deb1 = row.Index;
                        }
                        else if ((row.Cells["lotDataGridViewTextBoxColumn"].Value?.ToString() is "2") && (deb2 == 0))
                        {
                            deb2 = row.Index;
                            fin1 = row.Index - 1;
                        }
                        else if ((row.Cells["lotDataGridViewTextBoxColumn"].Value?.ToString() is "3") && (deb3 == 0))
                        {
                            fin2 = row.Index - 1;
                            deb3 = row.Index;
                        }
                    }
                    else if (row.Cells["TolerancesDataGridViewTextBoxColumn"].Value?.ToString() is "3")
                    {
                        if ((row.Cells["lotDataGridViewTextBoxColumn"].Value?.ToString() is "1") && (deb1 == 0))
                        {
                            deb1 = row.Index;
                        }
                        else if ((row.Cells["lotDataGridViewTextBoxColumn"].Value?.ToString() is "2") && (deb2 == 0))
                        {
                            deb2 = row.Index;
                            fin1 = row.Index - 1;
                        }
                        else if ((row.Cells["lotDataGridViewTextBoxColumn"].Value?.ToString() is "3") && (deb3 == 0))
                        {
                            fin2 = row.Index - 1;
                            deb3 = row.Index;
                        }
                    }
                }

                var cell1 = (DataGridViewTextBoxCellEx)dataGridView2.Rows[deb1].Cells["lotDataGridViewTextBoxColumn"];
                cell1.RowSpan = fin1 - deb1+1;
                var cell2 = (DataGridViewTextBoxCellEx)dataGridView2.Rows[deb2].Cells["lotDataGridViewTextBoxColumn"];
                cell2.RowSpan = fin2 - deb2+1;
                var cell3 = (DataGridViewTextBoxCellEx)dataGridView2.Rows[deb3].Cells["lotDataGridViewTextBoxColumn"];
                cell3.RowSpan = fin3 -deb3+2;

            }


            definitiondeslots();

            void donneesdemesures()
            {
                listBox1.Items.Clear();

                List<int> valeurs = new List<int>();
                var result = from DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView2.Rows where row.Visible select row;
                foreach (var row in result)
                {
                    string a = row.Cells[$"donnees{comboBox1.Text + comboBox2.Text}DataGridViewTextBoxColumn"].Value?.ToString();
                    if (!(a is ""))
                    {
                        valeurs.Add(Convert.ToInt32(a));
                    }
                    listBox1.Items.Add(a);

                }
                int b = valeurs.Max();

                for (int i = 1; i <= b; i++)
                {
                    dataGridView2.Columns.Add($"Test{i}", "Donnee");

                }


                foreach (var row in result)
                {
                    for (int i = 1; i <= b; i++)
                    {
                        row.Cells[$"Test{i}"] = new DataGridViewTextBoxCellEx();
                    }
                }
                int m = 0;
                foreach (var row in result)
                {
                    for (int i = 1; i <= b; i++)
                    {
                        row.Cells[$"Test{i}"].Style.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Gray;
                    }

                    for (int i = 1; i <= valeurs[m]; i++)
                    {
                        row.Cells[$"Test{i}"].Style.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;

                    }
                    m++;

                }

            }
            donneesdemesures();


        }
```

Would be really grateful if someone helped.

Comment: If you need to apply custom formatting to Cells, then subscribe to the `CellFormatting` event; or `CellPainting`, depending on the implementation and the type of work you have to do. Avoid looping the DGV's Rows

Comment: if i may ask, why exactly doesn't looping the rows/cells work? I know the issue comes from loops but I don't know why it exists.

Comment: The Cells are formatted each time you change *something*, then the RowTemplate's settings are applied to Rows, a Cell's or Column's `DefaultCellStyle` when required by the configuration, in a hierarchical order (the notes here could be useful: [Why are my DataGridView columns not colorizing as they should?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64721869/7444103)) -- Looping the Rows of a DGV is heavy (blocking) work and what you do may / will be overridden by defaults settings -- All in all, handling events for this is the intended behavior (what is subject to optimization)

Comment: Note that also mishandling `CellFormatting` can cause a lot of problems. This event is raised **very** often, so tread lightly. The lesser the better

Comment: Looks like a real challenge! I'll see what I can do and then update my post

Comment: @Jimi I really understood the issue, and I think I have a path for it. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Jimi's comment, I understood the whole process behind the cell formatting. So in order to avoid any overriding, just use the CellFormatting method, simply by following these steps :

Step 1: Go to the properties

[image: Step1]

Step2 : Click on the the lightning bolt

Step 3 : Look up the cellformatting function and double-click on it

Step 4 : Enter your code